# Tkinter add widget on scroolable frame last item does not shown

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a window that allows entering one-to-many fields for the file transfer.
I created a Scrollable Frame and I am adding Entry-Text pairs in runtime. If I click the button for the first time, everything goes well. After the second time, nothing happens on the UI side. It works perfectly after the second click. But I saw that all pairs added successfully, just the UI did not display it. Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
import tkinter as tk

class VerticalScroolFrame(tk.Frame):
    """A frame with a vertical scroolbar"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        main_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        main_frame.grid()

        main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, command=self._canvas.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W)

        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda *_: self.on_configure())

        super().__init__(self._canvas, *args, **kwargs)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self, anchor=tk.NW)

    def on_configure(self):
        """update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
        when all widgets are in self._canvas. And also need to be triggered
        whenever a widget added as a child.
        """
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))



class AdvancedTransfer:
    """Opens a window that allows you to enter source file list
    and targets for them. One-to-many relation.
    """
    def __init__(self, root):
        self._scroolable_frame = VerticalScroolFrame(root)
        self._entry_text_dict = {}

        self._button = tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=self.add_item)
        self._button.grid()

    def add_item(self):
        """Add entry-text widget group"""

        row = len(self._entry_text_dict)

        entry = tk.Entry(self._scroolable_frame)
        entry.insert(0, "row number: {0}".format(row))
        entry.grid(row=row, column=0)
        text = tk.Text(self._scroolable_frame)
        text.grid(row=row, column=1)

        self._entry_text_dict[entry] = text

        self._scroolable_frame.on_configure()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    main_frame.grid()

    AdvancedTransfer(main_frame)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Repro steps:

1. Run the code below.
2. Click the button two times.
3. You should see 2 pairs but only 1 pair shown instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you bind `<Configure>` event on wrong widget.  You should bind on the internal frame (i.e. instance of `VerticalScroolFrame`) instead of canvas (`self._canvas`):

```py
class VerticalScroolFrame(tk.Frame):
    """A frame with a vertical scroolbar"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        main_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        main_frame.grid()

        main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, command=self._canvas.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W)

        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        #self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda *_: self.on_configure())

        super().__init__(self._canvas, *args, **kwargs)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self, anchor=tk.NW)

        # bind <Configure> event on itself
        self.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: self.on_configure())
```